# Typescript: remove all `Function.prototype` methods

Tags: typescript, types, function.prototype

Is it possible to create this type: callable object (function) BUT without `Function.prototype` methods?

```
let callableObject = () => 'foo'
callableObject.bar = 'baz'

callableObject() // 'foo'
callableObject // {bar: 'baz'}
callableObject.call // error
```

I tried something like this with no success:

```
type ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods<T extends () => any> = {
    [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof Function>]: T[K]
}

function f<T extends () => any>(t: T): 
ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods<T> {
    return {} as any
}

f(() => {})() // the methods are excluded, but when calling,
  it fails with "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
  signature. Type 'ExcludeFunctionPrototypeMethods<() => void>' 
  has no compatible call signatures."
```

So maybe also the question should sound like "how do I add call signatures to the type"

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```js
function myFunc () {
  console.log('test');
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(myFunc, null);

// myFunc still works
myFunc();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myFunc))
```

Here we use `Object.setPrototype()` to set the prototype of the function object explicitly to `null`.

Comment: Hi, Willem! Thank you! But how can this be described as a type or interface? Actually I am more concerned about types.

Comment: Will try although haven't used TS in a while ;)

Comment: I think you can't, no one can't. I guess this is a limitation of TS, so I've created an issue (using your code btw): https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575 Thanks anyway!